# What is the minimum version of Cordova required to use the Marketing Cloud Cordova plugin?

Tags: marketing-cloud, cordova

I want to integrate this plugin : https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin into an already existing app that run Cordova 5.4.1.

I can install the plugin but when I try to build the app (for android) I get this mistake :

```
* What went wrong:
```

A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugCompile'.
>   Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.pom
>            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.jar
>            http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.pom
>            http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.jar
>            file:/C:/tools/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.pom
>            file:/C:/tools/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.jar
>            file:/C:/tools/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.pom
>            file:/C:/tools/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.jar
>        Required by:
>            :android:unspecified > com.salesforce.marketingcloud:marketingcloudsdk:5.2.0
>   Could not find com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-annotations/26.0.0/support-annotations-26.0.0.pom
>            file:/C:/tools/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/26.0.0/support-annotations-26.0.0.pom
>            file:/C:/tools/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/26.0.0/support-annotations-26.0.0.jar
>            file:/C:/tools/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/26.0.0/support-annotations-26.0.0.pom
>            file:/C:/tools/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-annotations/26.0.0/support-annotations-26.0.0.jar
>        Required by:
>            :android:unspecified > com.salesforce.marketingcloud:marketingcloudsdk:5.2.0
>   Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>            https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.pom
>            file:/C:/tools/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.pom
>            file:/C:/tools/android-sdk-windows/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.jar
>            file:/C:/tools/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.pom
>            file:/C:/tools/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/26.0.0/support-v4-26.0.0.jar
>        Required by:
>            :android:unspecified > com.salesforce.marketingcloud:marketingcloudsdk:5.2.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.0.1 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.0.1

I can make it work with a recent version of Cordova, but only after adding a line of code in the source code of the plugin itself.

As I understand, the app doesn't access the good repository and can't download the support library it needs.

Does anyone have already used this plugin ? Does it word with older version of cordova ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer in short upgrade to the latest **Cordova 7.x.x. but make sure you install the latest Android platform (Cordova Android 6.3.0)** Reference here: https://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2017/09/27/android-release.html#disqus_thread

To further explain. Our Cordova platform is currently:
https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin

```
Version 1.0.1

Released Nov 29, 2017

Depends on the Marketing Cloud Mobile Push iOS SDK v4.9.x
Depends on the Marketing Cloud Mobile Push Android SDK v5.2.x
```

Android SDK v5.2.x supports Android Oreo. Ref: http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/

...so we will need to grab Cordova's latest version that supports that. The older versions of Cordova for Android are supported in this cross reference chart here:
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/